# Query tab missing when linking external file to access database

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have an MS Access database (mdb) file on a Windows 2008 server.  It's in the "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\files\databases" folder.

I would like to link an external query to this database that is also on my server in the "e:\share\m_maping\files\databases" folder (also an Access .mdb file).  The e: drive is a partitioned drive on the server's only hard drive.

When I bring up the dialog to link this query, the tab for queries is not visible. I can see the tables tab but not the query tab.

Comment: You can import a query from another database.  But you can't create a link to a query in another database.  That is why queries are not displayed among the available link sources.

Comment: Can I create a odbc data source for this query.....are there any options to accomplishing this?

Comment: Your first comment is correct....I will have to find another way of getting the info from this external mdb.....thanks.

Comment: You can't create an ODBC link to the query, either.  Perhaps you could import the query's definition and create links to the query's data source tables.  Usually that will work.  Another possibility would be to save the query's result set data to a table in the remote database and then link to the table.  But then you would need to reload the table whenever the raw source data changes.  The appropriate solution depends on the details of what you have now and what you want.

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing....should have thought of this before but I had been looking at the problem too long and the specs kept changing.   Thanks

Comment: @HansUp That should be an answer, not a comment! :-)